# Uber API - HTTP Response with error code: 409

Tags: node.js, uber-api

I'm using the Uber API to create a ride request (with [node-uber](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber))

I first get the user authenticated (`uber.authorization` after getting a calback from `uber.getAuthorizeUrl`).

Then I call the estimate API and get a response (`estimates.getPriceForRoute`)

I then use the same start & end coordinates with the product ID returned in the estimate (`requests.create`).

I always get back: `HTTP Response with error code: 409`

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
Here is the code for the estimate request (which works perfectly)

```
router.get('/estimate', function(request, response, next) {
  var query = url.parse(request.url, true).query;

  if (!query || !query.start_lat || !query.start_lng || !query.end_lat || !query.end_lng) {
     response.sendStatus(400);
  } else {
     uber.estimates.getPriceForRoute(query.start_lat, query.start_lng, query.end_lat, query.end_lng , 1, function(err, res){
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    response.sendStatus(500);
  } else {
    var productType = getProductType(query);
    var selectedProduct = _.find(res.prices, function(price){
      return price.display_name == productType;
    });
    response.json(selectedProduct);
  }
});
```

}
});

Here is the response I get

> {"localized_display_name":"uberX","high_estimate":7,"minimum":7,"duration":240,"estimate":"$7-7","distance":0.95,"display_name":"uberX","product_id":"a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d","low_estimate":7,"surge_multiplier":1,"currency_code":"USD"}

Now the part that has the problem:

```
router.get('/request', function(request, response, next) {
  var query = url.parse(request.url, true).query;

  if (!query || !query.start_lat || !query.start_lng || !query.end_lat || !query.end_lng || !query.productId) {
    response.sendStatus(400);
  } else {
    uber.requests.create({
      "product_id": query.productId,
      "start_latitude": query.start_lat,
      "start_longitude": query.start_lng,
      "end_latitude": query.end_lat,
      "end_longitude": query.end_lng
    }, function (err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.error("error: " + err);
        response.sendStatus(400);
      } else {
        //console.log(res);
        response.json(res);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

the line `console.error("error: " + err);` returns this output:

> error: HTTP Response with error code: 409

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your source code? I assume you try to call /v1/requests/estimate endpoint. This [endpoints can return a 409 - Conflict](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-estimate). This status indicates that there is a surge in place right now. [Here is a description of the surge flow](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/tutorials-rides-api#creating-a-request):
[image]

The node-uber project does not actively support with handling a surge in the released version. However, there is a branch for v1.0.0 and someone started working on a direct support, [as listed in this issue conversation](https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber/issues/35).

Comment: I'm trying to call `requests.create`. I don't believe there is a constant surge. The estimate request shows no surge

Comment: Which product do you want to request? Please add some code to your question... Also, could you add a more detailed debug/error message? Thanks!